# Formatting the Swagger output for classes

Tags: php, restler

Is there a way to format the Swagger output in a better way when used with dummy classes?
For example:

`@return Account`

The output is kind of messy for me due to the lack of new lines:

[image: Messy class output from Swagger]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is created by swagger-ui at runtime, we will definitely be improving it over time
We may replace it with model representation as formatted json instead.

For now you may remove the @return comment and directly add the html you want (that places Response Information in the way you want) under the long description, it will show up the same way

You can copy paste the same html you get on explorer for this purpose

Also you don't have to do this for all api methods, only to those that have lot of fields and appear messy

Comment: Thanks! 
I was wondering is there a way to generate useful comments, that can be used in Swagger version of Restler based on the database schema, say from SQL file? Imagine 30 tables with 20-30 fields each table a lot of work will be done automatically.

Comment: looping through database and generating comment strings is easy, I have done that before